# In jsp page I can not access Model object returned from controller class

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

in controller class everything is working fine (as debugging says). But after returning to jsp page i can not display the model objects data. In jsp page there is no response.

**Controller**

```
public class controller_fetch extends model.modelclass {

    SqlRowSet srs = null;
    ArrayList arraylist = null;

    public List<String> list() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        arraylist = new ArrayList();

        try {
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            dataSource = new dbconnection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
            JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
            srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);
            while (srs.next()) {
                modelclass obj = new modelclass();
                obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
                obj.setPwd(srs.getString("pwd"));
                arraylist.add(obj);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arraylist;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getdata(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        List<String> arraylists = list();

        //return back to index.jsp
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("list");
        model.addObject("lists", arraylists);


        return model;

    }
}
```

**Jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${lists}" var="key">
<c:out value="${key.email_id}"></c:out>
<c:out value="${key.pwd}"></c:out>                
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you print the list on console and share the result

Answer (score 0):

Method is returning List , 
but while adding in list there is object
arraylist.add(obj);
What is modelclass ?

Also try to send simple string and see if it is printing in JSP.
Avoid using underscore in class name and variable name.

Comment: modelclass.java is gettersetter class

Comment: Return list should not List<String>,   it should be List<modelclass>.